# Получение картинки в base64

Tags: php

Налаживаю картинку 1 на 1 код таков

```
<?php
   $im = imagecreatefrompng("http://vii.com/templates/Default/images/inline_video_play.png");
    imagealphablending($im, false);
    imagesavealpha($im, true);
    $is = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://img.youtube.com/vi/5BQSEAyapNc/mqdefault.jpg");
    imagealphablending($is, true);
    imagecopy($is, $im, '140', '65', 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($is);
    imagedestroy($is);
    die();

?>
```

И Я хочу получить результат в base64 подскажите как реализовать?

Comment: http://www.php.su/base64_encode

Comment: Я понимаю что base64_encode , только что именно им кодировать ? какую переменную и тп

Comment: Добавил более развернутый ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким способом можно получить картинку в строковую переменную: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11446101/2101808.

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($im);
$imageString = ob_get_clean();
```

Дальше передаешь её в `base64_encode()` - на выходе опять же строка, к которой можно добавить контенттайп спереди и встроить в хтмл страницу или вывести отдельным файлом.